# List the combinations that add up to 0 from a vector of numbers

Tags: rust

I'm writing a function that, given a `Vec<i32>` of numbers, lists the combinations that add up to 0. The code works, but it feels amateurish.

Specifically, the inside of the loop looks really ugly -- there must be a simpler way of doing this that avoids `unwrap()` and the repetition. Maybe with `match`?

```
fn calc_zer(input: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<(i32, i32, i32)> {
    let mut output: Vec<(i32, i32, i32)> = Vec::new();
    for a in (0..input.len() - 2) {
        for b in (a+1..input.len() -1) {
            for c in (b+1..input.len()) {
                if (input.get(a).unwrap() + input.get(b).unwrap() + input.get(c).unwrap() == 0) {
                    output.push((*input.get(a).unwrap(), *input.get(b).unwrap(), *input.get(c).unwrap()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    output
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Rust is a statically-compiled language, which means you get warnings and errors at compile time. *Don't ignore those*:

   ```
   warning: unnecessary parentheses around `for` head expression
    --> src/main.rs:3:14
     |
   3 |     for a in (0..input.len() - 2) {
     |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: #[warn(unused_parens)] on by default

   warning: unnecessary parentheses around `for` head expression
    --> src/main.rs:4:18
     |
   4 |         for b in (a+1..input.len() -1) {
     |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: #[warn(unused_parens)] on by default

   warning: unnecessary parentheses around `for` head expression
    --> src/main.rs:5:22
     |
   5 |             for c in (b+1..input.len()) {
     |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: #[warn(unused_parens)] on by default

   warning: unnecessary parentheses around `if` condition
    --> src/main.rs:6:20
     |
   6 |                 if (input.get(a).unwrap() + input.get(b).unwrap() + input.get(c).unwrap() == 0) {
     |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: #[warn(unused_parens)] on by default
   ```
2. Next, run [Clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy) to get *even more automated suggestions*. Note that this contains the answer to your question:

   ```
   warning: this argument is passed by value, but not consumed in the function body
    --> src/main.rs:1:24
     |
   1 | pub fn calc_zer(input: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<(i32, i32, i32)> {
     |                        ^^^^^^^^ help: consider changing the type to `&[i32]`
     |
     = note: #[warn(needless_pass_by_value)] on by default
     = help: for further information visit https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/wiki#needless_pass_by_value

   warning: called `.get().unwrap()` on a Vec. Using `[]` is more clear and more concise
    --> src/main.rs:6:20
     |
   6 |                 if input.get(a).unwrap() + input.get(b).unwrap() + input.get(c).unwrap() == 0 {
     |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: try this `&input[a]`
     |
     = note: #[warn(get_unwrap)] on by default
     = help: for further information visit https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/wiki#get_unwrap
   ```
3. Extract local variables so you don't even have the overhead of accessing the array multiple times.
4. There's no reason to provide an explicit type for `output` - it will be inferred from the return value.
5. Extract a variable for `input.len()` since that never changes during the iteration.
6. It's almost always better to iterate over the collection directly instead of indexing it. We can also use `Iterator::enumerate` to get the index as we go along.

This yields

```
fn calc_zer(input: &[i32]) -> Vec<(i32, i32, i32)> {
    let mut output = Vec::new();

    let len = input.len();

    for (a_i, &a) in input[0..len - 2].iter().enumerate() {
        for (b_i, &b) in input[a_i + 1..len - 1].iter().enumerate() {
            for &c in &input[a_i + b_i + 2..len] {
                if a + b + c == 0 {
                    output.push((a, b, c));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    output
}
```

This is a bit ugly, and even worse — I got it wrong originally! See [the revision history](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/169279/revisions) for details. This was caused because `enumerate` starts counting from zero, even though we are iterating through an offset into the original vector.

However, Rust has a **strong** emphasis on reusing code via crates. In this example, I turn to one of my favorites — [itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.6.0/itertools/):

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;

fn calc_zer(input: &[i32]) -> Vec<(i32, i32, i32)> {
    input.iter()
        .tuple_combinations()
        .filter(|&(a, b, c)| a + b + c == 0)
        .map(|(&a, &b, &c)| (a, b, c))
        .collect()
}
```

Much more readable!

Comment: The first implementation is incorrect. It will return results like `(-2, 1, 1)` from the input `[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]`. The reason is that `x..y-z != x..y - z` (yes you can subtract from `Range`). You need less spaces or more parenthesis :)

Comment: @jacwah it certainly was incorrect, thank you for pointing that out. However, you [can not subtract from `Range`](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=7c6464445e8d39e4abd5e7db6e359ea6&version=stable)! You gave me a scare there, as I wasn't sure how I'd never seen that before; good thing it doesn't exist ^_^.

Comment: Hmm, what's going on here?? It's fairily uninuitive that spacing should make difference in the first place.

Comment: @jacwah that's good then because spacing is not the problem. The problem is the `enumerate` call starting at zero.

Comment: Oh I feel stupid now. I was testing a bunch of versions of `calc_zer` and just for fun tried changing the spacing, and I thought it worked. I must have run the wrong function. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: About the `&`'s sprinkled around -- I'm familiar enough with pointers and references in C++, but Rust is still confusing me. Why are we using `input` in the first two loops but `&input` in the third? Because the `.iter().enumerate()` already gives a reference?

Comment: @DanAmbrogio a `for` loop takes any type that implements [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html). Calling `input.iter()`, calling `input.iter().enumerate()`, using `&input` and using `input` all return types that implement that trait. In *this* case, we need the `&` because we are slicing the input iterator — without the `&` we'd be trying to create an *unsized type* that's not behind a pointer. The first two loops don't need it because the call to `iter` implies the reference. It could have been `for &c in input[a_i + b_i + 2..len].iter()` to be consistent

Answer (score 2):

Let's do some complexity analysis! Your algorithm searches all combinations \${n \choose 3}\$ which is cubic time. We can improve this by sorting and being smarter about which triplets we visit.

For instance, say we have the the vector `[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]`. We start by looking at `(-2, -1, 2)`, whose sum is less than zero. Thus, we can rule out all `(-2, -1, x)` triplets since all remaining `x` are less than 2.

```
fn calc_zer(input_slice: &[i32]) -> Vec<(i32, i32, i32)> {
    let mut input = input_slice.to_vec();
    input.sort();
    let mut output = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..input.len() - 1 {
        let mut l = i + 1;
        let mut r = input.len() - 1;

        while l < r {
            let sum = input[i] + input[l] + input[r];

            if sum == 0 {
                output.push((input[i], input[l], input[r]));
                l += 1;
                r -= 1;
            } else if sum < 0 {
                l += 1;
            } else {
                r -= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    output
}
```

Here is the code, adapted from the GeeksForGeeks article linked below. It goes through each element, matches it with a `(smallest, largest)` pair and adjusts the pair if the sum is negative or positive.

This algorithm spends \$O(n \lg n)\$ time sorting and \$O(n)\$ time per element (the while loop), which yields a quadratic time complexity.

I compared the two algorithms by running them on a 1000 element input. The cubic algorithm took 4 minutes. The quadratic half a second.

Resources:

- [Find all triplets with zero sum](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-triplets-array-whose-sum-equal-zero/)
- [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM)
- [Similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524919/3sum-finding-all-unique-triplets-in-a-list-that-equal-0)

Answer (score 2):

Shepmaster's solution with Itertools is fine (I assume it works) and may be the best way to go, in an absolute sense, but I don't believe it's the answer you were looking for.  If you're still learning Rust you probably aren't familiar enough with the standard libraries to even know about `tuple_combinations()`.  I think you wanted to fix your implementation rather than replace it with another.  The fact that the other may somehow be better doesn't seem to be the point here.

Your gut told you, *"the inside of the loop looks really ugly -- there must be a simpler way of doing this that avoids unwrap() and the repetition"*, so that's what I'll address.

**uglyness:**  You have a lot of code that doesn't need to be there.  Most of it is the `unwrap()` calls.  Eliminating them will improve things.  You don't need to declare a type for `output` since it's the return type—that may not always be true but it is here.

**unwrap():**  Why use `get()`?  You have a vector (better yet, a slice) which supports indexing via `[ ]` notation.  *Boom*—no more `unwrap()`.

This is what I belive your solution should be:

```
pub fn calc_zer(input: &[i32]) -> Vec<(i32, i32, i32)> {
    let mut output = Vec::new();
    let end = input.len();
    for a in 0..end-2 {
        for b in a+1..end-1 {
            for c in b+1..end {
                let x = (input[a], input[c], input[c]);
                if x.0 + x.1 + x.2 == 0 { output.push(x); }
            }
        }
    }
    output
}
```

The only improvement I can claim is subjective; clarity. It's visually neat and tidy. There is less code to read, less to understand. That makes it easier to edit. That could support a claim of less error prone, but it's arguable.